# I can't get my Chrome Extension to load Jquery, eventhough it's included in manifest

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm really needing some help on this one. I've created a chrome extension that uses jquery. I've included the jquery file in my manifest, before my javascript file, and the minified version is included in my project folder (I've renamed it jquery.js), and I still get " $ undefined" when I try to run the extension. Any ideas?? Here is my manifest.json:

```
{ "name": "Sisterhood Chrome Extension",
"description": "Override the standard new tab page with a page from Wikipedia about a woman who has made history",

  "version": "1",

"background": {
"scripts": "jquery.js",

"persistent": false
},

"content_scripts": [ {

"js": ["jquery.js", "sister.js"],

"matches":["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}],

"chrome_url_overrides": 
{
"newtab": "sister.html"
},
"manifest_version": 2

}
```

Comment: If you want to use jquery in `sister.html` you need to include it there, not in your manifest.

Comment: And having jquery in a background script does nothing.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked. Now that you said it it seems pretty obvious, so I'm sorry for the question! I'm learning. Thanks again!